# 301 will not redirect to Facebook page

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-401, mod-alias

In Google search console, I have 3 url's that will not redirect. They are all facebook url's and are similar to this:

```
Redirect 301 /author/amy/feed/%20www.facebook.com/heatfinders https://www.facebook.com/heatfinders
```

I'm pretty sure its something to do with the '%' in the url. Still getting a 401 instead of it going to the correct Facebook page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RedirectMatch` and `\s` to match a space in the uri.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/author/amy/feed/\swww\.facebook\.com/heatfinders$ https://www.facebook.com/heatfinders
```